# Create a New Directory Folder in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

const fs = require('fs');

```
 const path = require('path');

   fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '/Foldername'), {}, err => {
      if(err) throw err;
console.log('Your Folder Has Been Created SuccessFully');
```

---

});

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

create a variable called '__dirname' and assign the path to it. Don't forget you escape characters. Something like:

```
const __dirname = "C:\\git"
```